# Qgis 2.14 Changing line and buffer at the same time

Tags: qgis, buffer

I have created many buffers for a line shapefile, but now I have to change the line path and would like the buffers to change automatically. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Once a buffer is created, it is its own vector feature independent from the original feature it was calculated from.

Depending on your required result, there are ways to forego creating buffers in the first place, like using Spatial Query, but it depends on what your requirements is.

If your work regularly requires creating buffers, you should automate the process with either a model or a script. That way, any time the original data changes, creating the resulting buffers will be quick and easy.